# Passiv Präteritum vs passiv perfekt

Tags: grammaticality, passive

> - In der BRD ist die Demokratie eingeführt worden.
> - In der BRD wurde die Demokratie eingeführt.

Both represent passive in the past and I really don't know when to use each one. Is there a difference in the meaning? Or are both structures interchangeable?

Comment: Das Verb einführen wird mit dem Hilfsverb haben konjugiert:<br> er/sie/es wurde eingeführt = Präteritum<br> er/sie/es ist eingeführt worden = Perfekt<br> you have to add "worden", the tense requires the auxiliary verb

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference of meaning is in the perspective on the process of action:

> In der BRD ist die Demokratie eingeführt worden

emphasises that democracy has been established and is now, currently, present. The action of introducing it has finished. The focus is on the result of the action.

> In der BRD wurde die Demokratie eingeführt

emphasises the process itself. The sentence would typically be part of a longer story with other actions preceding and following. E.g.

> Erst wurde die BRD gegründet. Dann wurde in ihr die Demokratie eingeführt. In der Folge wurden alle ein bisschen schläfrig, und der rechte Mob machte sich wieder breit, ausgehend von den vergessenen Winkeln des Landes.

All this is told as a sequence of consecutive events. The focus is on the action "on the go".

Comment: Now it is clearer! One question: If I said ( In der BRD ist die Demokratie eingeführt ) without saying "worden".Doesn't it imply the same meaning? I mean what did worden add to the meaning of the sentence?